# Can Zend Framework run fully without Zend Server?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-server

We are resurrecting some old code that used the Zend framework. The old code extends several Zend classes, invokes getOptions() and uses some other Zend functions. We tried installing Zend Framework with XAMPP (click [here](http://mattbearman.com/2010/05/18/how-to-install-zend-framework-with-xampp/)) without the Zend Server. We have loads of errors that prevent the legacy site from rendering properly.

Is Zend Server necessary to use all the methods, etc. of Zend Framework?

Comment: afaik, there is no need to use a zend server. we also running old projects with zf1 and using a simple apache for them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can run Zend Framework without Zend Server (and I'd guess this is a much more common setup than using both together). The only thing I can think of in ZF that would require Zend Server would be the [Zend Server Cache Backend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.cache.backends.html#zend.cache.backends.zendserver).

It's more likely that your issue is down to a difference in configuration between your old server and new. If you can give examples of some of the errors you're getting we might be able to suggest where to look.

Comment: Thanks...I was able to solve our issues. You were right...we don't need Zend Server.

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob Do you have any tips for running an old Zend Framework app on an Apache server (w/out Zend Server)? Or is there an online tutorial you'd recommend?